# How to change the background color of a bootstrap dropdown list and expanding menu

Tags: html

I want to change the default background color of bootstrap dropdownlist and also the back color of its expanding menu. I had already tried it using my custom CSS, but it remains the same. below is my code

Html code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" i crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.0.4/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/vertex_logo.png" style="width:80px;height:80px"> 
</a>
</nav>

<div class="container features">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12"> 
    <div class="signin-div">
<h3 class="feature-title">Login Here..</h3>
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- Basic dropdown -->
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<!-- Basic dropdown -->
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
.btn-primary{
background-color: #68889E;
}
.dropdown-menu{
background-color: #6ab446;
border: 1px solid #D9534F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your CSS *after* the Bootstrap CSS. So you need to swap those two lines to read:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" i crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"><!-- AFTER Bootstrap! -->
```

This allows your code to override the Boostrap CSS, which is included first.

Also, what's with the lone `i` attribute in your `<link>` tag? It looks like a typo; I suggest you remove it.

You can also change any of the dropdown states:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: back color of dropdown menu changed successfully, but back color of dropdownlist has no change

Comment: which'  i' attribute you mean? can't underatand that

Comment: What's the difference between "dropdown menu" and "dropdownlist"?

Comment: I am referring to the lone `i`, just before the `crossorigin`, in your `<link>` tag:
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" `i` crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: i just mention the sub menu of the dropdownlist as dropdownmenu.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can change the background of various parts of the dropdown.